# Morphia problems during filter arrays by date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

I have those classes:

```
@Entity
public class Event implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private ObjectId id;

@Embedded
private List<Edition> editions;
...
}
```

and

```
public class Edition implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Date schedule;

...
}
```

I am trying search an Event and filter by an date less than edition schedule.

For instance, if I have an collection such:

```
{
  id : <ObjectID>,
  editions : [
    {schedule : 2014-1-1},
    {schedule : 2014-1-2}
  ]
}
```

If I search by 2014-1-3 I expect no results.

If I search by 2014-1-1 the result that I am expecting is:

```
{
  id : <ObjectID>,
  editions : [
    {schedule : 2014-1-2}
  ]
}
```

If I search by 2013-12-31 the result I am expecting is:

```
{
  id : <ObjectID>,
  editions : [
    {schedule : 2014-1-1},
    {schedule : 2014-1-2}
  ]
}
```

My problem is with the last case.

```
Query<Event> query = this.basicDAO.createQuery();
query = query.filter("editions.schedule >", <start date>);
return this.basicDAO.find(query).retrievedFields(true, "editions.$").asList();
```

When I try that last query I receive just one edition, however, those two match with clause. There is some clause to tell that I want all registries which match and not only the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, the [projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) only finds the first element matching.

In general, is your document structure really the best fit for your requirements? Specifically, do you need to embed the `Edition`s? MongoDB will always read the full `Event` document (fetch it from RAM or disk). So if you are frequently fetching the `Edition` only, embedding is probably the wrong approach.

In case embedding is required, because you are frequently requiring the full `Event`, I'm afraid the easiest approach is to fetch the full document and put together the right pieces of information in your application. This adds some network and application overhead.

Comment: Thanks @xeraa. In my case I need to read the full Event. I will try split some pieces to put then together